# How to make two foreach "work" at the same time / parallel / async

Tags: c#, .net

I am having a question about c# programming.
I got this code provided under which I want to parallelise or make it run async.
I got a storyList which contain a list of categories and data. I want to work on each list parallele since they are independent of each other.
How can I achieve that foreach storelist and foreach data both iterates at the same time?

```
public void workwithitems(List<StoreModel> StoreList)
{
            foreach (var item in StoreList)
            {
                foreach (var entry in item.categories) {
                    Items.Add(new item
                    {
                       Name = item.Name                     
                    });
                }
                foreach (var item in item.Data) {
                    Items.Add(new item
                    {
                      Name = item.Name                     
                    });
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: note that `List<T>` is not a thread-safe container.

Comment: i suggest implementing a separate `Thread` for both.

Comment: Adding items to a list is *very* fast.  What are you expecting to gain by parallelizing it?

Comment: You can parallelise it with Parallel.ForEach() but you will have get a Problem when Add is called from 2 threads at the same time. You will have to invoke it but then you lose parallelization

Comment: There is no reason to parallelize this, as the handling ends up with `Items.Add` which I presume should by synchronized anyway - so essentially you will get the same sequential execution burdened by parallelization overhead.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Tasks

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.StartNew(() => { foreach number 1...});
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.StartNew(() => { foreach number 2...});
```

Answer (score 2):

Put them in methods and according to TPL you can do something like this:

```
Parallel.Invoke(() => MethodWithForeach(), () => MethodWithOtherForeach());
```